# SQL Server select looks like 'Like'

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

I have question about SQL Server's `LIKE` operator.

I have a table `Table1`:

```
app    ex  
----------
test   210
```

I am writing some select from program select is looks like this:

```
select app 
from Table1 
where ex Like = '210203'
```

I have tried to use (`%,%.%,[]`).

If I try `[]` this one like this [210]203 it is working but there will be more data so if there will be 2102 in ex I want this to choose this one.

But it isn't selecting nothing beacouse ver is 210203 and in ex is 210

How can I manage this that I selected 210  the variable can't be changed there will be always variable bigger than 'ex' data

Please help me anyone.

Comment: check here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Comment: This query has an obvious syntax error. Apart from that, the question doesn't make much sense. What is it supposed to do? Not how, not `kinda like`, what. Find rows with a certain prefix? Rows where `ex` contains a string anywhere in it? A string at the end? Rows between `210...` and `211...` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You query is not right, you don't use "=" operator in Like.

```
SELECT app FROM Table1 WHERE ex LIKE '%210%'
```

In this case will filter values who have 210 inside.

If you use for ex: `Like ='%210'` will filter values who ends with 210.. and so on.

**Update**

You can use this too, i think will help you

```
declare @Value varchar(50)
set @value = '123AAAAA123'

select * from Table where @Value like '%' + column + '%'
```

Comment: yah but the problem is that i can't cut the number that is coming it is kinda like contains  or like but viseversa

Comment: But still can't understand what you are really trying to do ?

Comment: @Wuhu what are you trying to do? There's no `kinda like contains but viseversa`. If you want to use wildcards, you use wildcards.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos still can't understand here

Comment: veriable wich is passed is always bigger than data wich is in table so it is not selecting anything

Comment: So you for example, receive like 1221032 and your data in db is only 210?

Comment: Wuhu please edit your question and give us more sample data and expected outcome. It is not clear what you are asking

Comment: @Wuhu take a look in the code, i updated the answer.

Comment: May I add my 2 cents. You can use: where ex like (select '123123')
He he he